# has_many association with select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-relation

all!
I want to create additional has_many relation to select only needed columns

Example

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "pricelist_prices"
  has_many :order_items, :primary_key=> :city_id, :foreign_key=> :city_id
  has_many :orders, :through => :order_items   
end
```

so it works now. But I would like to create association which works like :orders, but have :select option

Example

```
has_many :orders, :through => :order_items, :select=>"price"
```

But I don't want to override current :orders accociation.
How to do this?

UPD
Azoto show example with source option!
It's ok, but when I use this accotiation in includes , it doesn't work.

```
 Price.where(:id=>[12759,12758]).includes(:prices_from_orders)
   (Object doesn't support #inspect)

   Price.where(:id=>[12759,12758]).includes(:prices_from_orders).first
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@new/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:88:in `block in associated_records_by_owner'
```

UPD2

I realized problem, if you want to use such assotioation in includes method, also add primary_key selection, otherway AR don't know who is an owner of record.

```
has_many :orders, :through => :order_items, :select=>"id, price"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a new `relation` that does `select` price.

```
has_many :price_of_orders, :through => :order_items,
                           :source => orders,
                           :select => :price
```

**OR**

How about an [association extension](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+extensions)?.

```
has_many :orders, :through => :order_items do
  def just_price
    select(:price)
  end
end
```

Then you could do something like `@price.orders.just_price`

Comment: thanks! It works ! But when I use it in includes it raise an error (
updated question

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Rails 4 and after, use the following code:

```
has_many :order_prices, -> {
  select('orders.price')
} :through => order_items
```